# How to use extended Jackson MapSerializer in Hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson

I'm trying to extend the 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer to include some of my own defined functions to be used in serialize() method.

```
public class MyMapSerializer extends MapSerializer{
    //have constructors
    //override method
    @Override
     public void serialize(Map<?,?> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider){}
}
```

Then I add the annotation to my map as folllowing:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = org.entities.generator.MyMapSerializer.class)
private Map<ObjectA,ObjectB> myObject;
```

But when I add a breakpoint in the MapSerializer, it does not even go into it.
And I tried to extend JsonSerializer>, it goes into it.
Anyone knows how to use the extended MapSerializer?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would not recommend trying to sub-class Jackson's default serializers: this is fragile.

But if you do want to do it, have a look at `MapSerializer`: my guess is that its `createContextual()` method ends up constructing a differently configured instance. You may need to override one of other methods which handled creationg of such instances; you just need those to construct instanceof `MyMapSerializer` instead of default `MapSerializer`.