# Jackson: Add dynamic field to Map serialization (sth like @JsonAppend)

Tags: java, json, dictionary, serialization, jackson

Something like a simplified Version of @JsonAppend

```
public class Bean {

    @JsonAppend(key = [...], value = [...])
    public Map<?, ?> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

would be great - any simple way to achieve this?

I've read lot's of SO entries, eg.

- [Add dynamic fields to Spring JSON view response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156264/add-dynamic-fields-to-spring-json-view-response)
- [Jackson: How to add custom property to the JSON without modifying the POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714328/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo)
- [Jackson's @JsonAppend with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787066/jacksons-jsonappend-with-default-value)
- [Jackson :: adding extra fields to an object in serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362247/jackson-adding-extra-fields-to-an-object-in-serialization)
- [How to use extended Jackson MapSerializer in Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249909/how-to-use-extended-jackson-mapserializer-in-hashmap)
- [Jackson custom annotation for custom value serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342097/jackson-custom-annotation-for-custom-value-serialization)

but found nothing matching my needs.

The reason for my request is that it is indistinguishable whether some given JSON originated from Map or POJO serialization. If this is necessary (in rare cases), adding a magic extra field to the map would be a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: As commented I appreciate @lppeds detailed answer!

Another very simple solution which came to my mind *after* submitting my question is the introduction of a naming convention e.g. "if some key ends (case insensitive) on 'map' and the corresponding value is an object then the value is a serialized map"... ;-) But of course it's not always possible (or desirable) to introduce such naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! Yes, this is (somehow) possible. The following exposed methodology maintains the standard serialization behavior, while adding on top of it annotation-defined key-value pairs.

---

Create a custom annotation. I'll call it `MapAppender`

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MapAppender {
    String[] keys();
    String[] values();
}
```

As you can see, we define key-value arrays, which will match by index.
We are forced using `String` fields instead of the more generic `Object`, but that's per annotation design.

Create a custom `JsonSerializer<Map>`. I'll call it `MapAppenderSerializer`

```
public class MapAppenderSerializer
        extends StdSerializer<Map>
        implements ContextualSerializer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final String[] keys;
    private final String[] values;

    // No-arg constructor required for Jackson
    MapAppenderSerializer() {
        super(Map.class);
        keys = new String[0];
        values = new String[0];
    }

    MapAppenderSerializer(
            final String[] keys,
            final String[] values) {
        super(Map.class);
        this.keys = keys;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
            final Map value,
            final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
            final SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        // Create a copy Map to avoid touching the original one
        final Map hashMap = new HashMap<>(value);

        // Add the annotation-specified key-value pairs
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            hashMap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
        }

        // Serialize the new Map
        serializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(hashMap, jsonGenerator);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(
            final SerializerProvider serializerProvider,
            final BeanProperty property) {
        MapAppender annotation = null;

        if (property != null) {
            annotation = property.getAnnotation(MapAppender.class);
        }

        if (annotation != null) {
            return new MapAppenderSerializer(annotation.keys(), annotation.values());
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
    }
}
```

Now, using your `Bean` class example, annotate the `Map` field with `@MapAppender` and define a custom serializer using `@JsonSerialize`

```
public class Bean {
    public String simpleField;

    @MapAppender(keys = {"test1", "test2"}, values = {"value1", "value2"})
    @JsonSerialize(using = MapAppenderSerializer.class)
    public Map<Object, Object> simpleMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

That's it. Serializing an instance of `Bean`

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String string = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Bean());
```

results in

```
{"simpleField":null,"simpleMap":{"test2":"value2","test1":"value1"}}
```

---

Another example, having the `Map` populated with values prior to serialization

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final Bean value = new Bean();
value.simpleMap.put("myKey", "myValue");

final String string = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
```

results in

```
{"simpleField":null,"simpleMap":{"test1":"value1","test2":"value2","myKey":"myValue"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Looks easier, than the stuff I've come up with. ;-)